# How do you get legal advice on a question from a lawyer?

Tags: united-states, lawyer, advice

It's common to respond to requests for specific legal advice on this site with something along the lines of "you need to hire a lawyer." I've said it myself. However, I'm not exactly sure what it involves. If I just want to know whether or not something is legal, or have some other question to ask a lawyer (not a case that will require continuing work; just a question), how exactly do I hire a lawyer? Do I do it in person at the lawyer's office? Do I call? Do I do something online? How much should I expect to pay?

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you call, briefly discuss what you want, and schedule a meeting for paid consultation. The charge for a one hour consultation would vary greatly but would typically be $100-$500. You may need to sign a fee agreement and provide a retainer for the fees to be paid in advance, but different lawyers have different policies.

Answer (score 2):

### The same way you get medical advice from a doctor

You contact them, explain your issue, and arrange an appointment.